# increasing the size of a textbox using CSS

Tags: css

I need to increase the size of a textbox upwards, upon hover. i want it to be fixed from the bottom.
Can anyone tell me how is it possible using CSS only?
Thanks

Comment: input{
      bottom:0;      
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;} 

input:hover
{
    height: 70px;
    width: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you can achieve that is with the help of the top margins, here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/nKSC3/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
input{position:absolute;bottom:0;}
input:hover{padding-top:20px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HmAh4/

Comment: thanks, but i need to increase the box hieght upwards. bottom: 0 doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I mean, it works in the jsfiddle.  Give us more info if you want a solution better tailored to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Textbox{position:absolute;bottom:0; height:20px;}
#Textbox:hover{height:40px;}
```

You might also want to change the font-size upon doing this and make sure no other control depends on your textbox's positioning or else you would see unwanted after-effects.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that uses a negative top margin

```
textarea{height:100px;}
textarea:hover{margin-top:-20px;height:120px;}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HmAh4/2/)